# Can I change the payment intent amount?

Tags: stripe-payments

Does Stripe support the change of payment intent amount?

Here is my use case:

1. a customer checkout a ticket listed as price of $50, so our system hold a payment intent of $50;
2. we don't charge the $50 unless the event starts, and there are two potential situations:

   - if the event gets cancelled, our system will cancel the payment intent (i.e., not capture it);
   - if the event changed to a different performer, our system will reduce the amount of payment intent (i.e., capture $25 instead of $50)

Is the above use case doable with Stripe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just update the PaymentIntent with the new amount will do.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update

Comment: if the customer paid using Stripe checkout then it will not allow you to update the amount field in the PaymentIntent object. When I did it I got: "com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: Some of the parameters you provided (amount) cannot be used when modifying a PaymentIntent that was created by Checkout. You can try again without those parameters.". Then I tried to update the Charge object, but it doesn't have an amount field. Then I tried to use the Refund API where I passed the PaymentIntent and the refund amount and I got another error that I cannot do a refund in a PaymentIntent

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed your total amount with JavaScript, then enter this code after custom logic

```html
jQuery('#total_amount_field_id').trigger('change');
```